# for an onClick function, how do I make it so that it gives me the next element in a list from current?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, skip, anagram

I'm working on an anagram app for android in android studio.  I'm currently working on a "skip" method to skip the current word from the list and show me the next word in the list.  I need a button to do this, but every time I click it, it brings me to the last element.  I'm guessing every time the method is called, it just iterates from beginning to end and shows me the last element.

```
    public void skip (View v){
        TextView scrambleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrambleView);

        for (ListIterator<String> i = wordBank.listIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String item = i.next();
            scrambleView.setText(scramble(r, item));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the next value, why do you use a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop (I don't truly understand why did you use it), just get the next value from the list:

```
public void skip (View v){

    TextView scrambleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrambleView);
    String item = wordBank.get(next_index);
    scrambleView.setText(scramble(r, item));

}
```

If you don't know the index, you can use a method such as this:

```
public String getNext(String yourWord) {
       int idx = wordBank.indexOf(yourWord);
       if (idx < 0 || idx+1 == myList.size())
           return "";

       return wordBank.get(idx + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a loop in the first place.  You could just use:

```
public void skip (View v){
    TextView scrambleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrambleView);
    String item=wordBank.listIterator().next();
    scrambleView.setText(scramble(r, item));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm not really sure why I used a loop in the first place (brain fart or something), but with this code it will display the next item in the list, but when clicked again it brings up the same word (should go to the next word in the list).  Also I should note that when the game is started, the first word of the list (index 0) is the default displayed.